# Datatable column sort definition

Tags: datatables

I have a column where I render data. However, when I render the data, the order is sorted based on the rendered text, not the original data.

I have looked at [the docs about column ordering](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data), but it doesn't seem to cover my situation.

My data looks like this:

```
name   | date
-------+-------------
Second | 2023-11-03
Zeroth | 2023-11-08
```

This is what I have vs what I want:

```
Current Order:               Intended Order:
------------------------     -------------------------
Second | Friday 11/03        Zeroth | Wednesday 11/08  <= Orders on the data not the render
Zeroth | Wednesday 11/08     Second | Friday 11/03
```

DataTable creation:

```
$('#my-dt').DataTable({
  data    : [
              ['Second' , '2023-11-03'],
              ['Zeroth' , '2023-11-03']
            ],

  order   : [[ 1,'desc' ]],  // This works only if there is no render
              
    
  columns : [ 
              { title: 'Name'},
              { title: 'Date',
                order:  data,    // << This is what I'd like to do. How can I accomplish this?

                render (     data ){
                  return myGetDayOfWeek(data)
                }
              }
            ]
})
```